# Access objects/methods outside of useEffect in React/Three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-props, use-ref

I need to add controls for manipulating the rubiks object that is declared in useEffect. The controls are a series of buttons that need to call functions built into the cube class (of which rubiks belongs to) that exist in a separate component named 'ControlBar'. I tried using useRef and declare the object above useEffect but I get an error when trying to pass the reference of the rubiks object to ControlBar with "ref={rubiks}". I also attempted to use props but also wasn't successful. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

CubeContainer Component:

```
const CubeContainer = () => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const playground = document.getElementById('playground');

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        //@ts-ignore
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, playground?.offsetWidth / playground?.offsetHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        camera.position.set(5,5,5);

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        // @ts-ignore
        renderer.setSize( playground?.offsetWidth, playground?.offsetHeight );
        playground?.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xababab, 1 );
        scene.add(light);

        let rubiks = new Cube(scene);
        rubiks.build();
        const fullCube = rubiks.getParentObj();
        
        scene.add(fullCube);
        
        //@ts-ignore
        const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, playground);

        // camera.worldToLocal(fullCube.position)
        const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 1 );
        scene.add( axesHelper );
        

        function animate() {
            
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update()
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

        animate(); 
        
    }); 

    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-span-5 row-span-5 playarea">
                <div id="playground"  className="h-full"></div>
            </div>
            <MoveBar />
            <ControlBar /> <
        </>
    );
}

export default CubeContainer;
```

ControlBar Component:

```
const ControlBar = () => {

    return (
        <div className="col-span-7 bg-zinc-800">
            <div className="col-span-5 text-center inline-block">
                <div className="float-left">
                    <FButton/>
                    <F_Button/>
                </div>
                <div className="float-left">
                    <RButton/>
                    <R_Button/>
                </div>
                <div className="float-left">
                    <UButton/>
                    <U_Button/>
                </div>
                <div className="float-left">
                    <DButton/>
                    <D_Button/>
                </div>
                <div className="float-left">
                    <LButton/>
                    <L_Button/>
                </div>
                <div className="float-left">
                    <BButton/>
                    <B_Button/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-2 float-left">
                    <ShuffleButton/>
                    <SolveButton/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ControlBar;
```

Sample Button Component:

```
const FButton = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <div className="colspan-7">
            <button className="turn-button-class" onClick={props.rotateFaceClickHandler}>F</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FButton;
```

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of imperative code that doesn't mesh with React's declarative style. Have you considered a library which wraps this up to make it React-friendly? This looks promising: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber

Answer (score 0):

Just declare cube outside of useEffect,
then you can reference it.
Also pass an empty array to useEffect as the second parameter so it just runs  once.
Also I recommend to use a useRef as as a reference to your playground div.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).